# Cannot find symbol when using Subimage

Tags: java, symbols

When I am using subimages, java throws me this:

```
Pacman.java:152: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getSubImage(int,int,int,int)
location: class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
                cherry = sprite.getSubImage(0, 0, 38, 38);
                               ^
```

In current code:

```
    class DerpPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {


        public BufferedImage image, image2;
        public BufferedImage sprite, cherry, ghost;


    public DerpPanel() {
        frame.addKeyListener(this);


            image = ImageIO.read(new File("ghost.png"));
            image2 = ImageIO.read(new File("fruit.png"));

            sprite = ImageIO.read(new File("sprite.png"));
            cherry = sprite.getSubImage(0, 0, 38, 38);
            ghost = sprite.getSubImage(38, 38, 38, 38);



        Mover mover = new Mover();
        Timer timer = new Timer(3000, mover);
        Pacmann pacmann = new Pacmann();
        Timer timer2 = new Timer(500, pacmann);
        timer.start();
        timer2.start();

    } //end public DerpPanel
} //fake DerpPanel ending
```

Does anybody have any idea why? I've imported the correct libraries.

Complete code here:

> [Code](https://github.com/lele0108/Java/blob/master/Pacman/Pacman.java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `getSubimage`, not `getSubImage` (no capital "I").